# reactJS url params name stay in url when are optionnal

Tags: reactjs, router, react-router-dom

I am a beginner with ReactJS and i am in trouble with the optionnal parameters in url.

I use react-router-dom 5.1.2.

When i try to create a Route with a component which have a optionnal parameters, this route will keep the parameters name if there is no values for params. If i create a Link with parameter all works fine.

For example in my sideBar the path to access to AudioComponent is (the link is generated with the route component):

```
<a class="sidebar-link" href="/callcenter/soundplayer/:agentName?/:date?">Audios</a>
```

My componentRoute :

```
{
  path: "/callcenter/soundplayer/:agentName?/:date?",
  name: "Audios",
  component: SoundFileRow,
  isShow: true,
  access: "staffAccess"
},
```

And my Routes.js (I download a template so the Route code was already like that, except for conditions)

```
const childRoutes = (Layout, routes, navBarAccess) =>   routes.map(({ children, path, realPath, component: Component, access }, index) =>
    children ? (
      // Route item with children
      children.map(({ path, component: Component , access}, index) => (
        <Route
          key={index}
          path={path}
          exact
          render={props => (
            (checkIsAuth())? 
            checkHasAccess(access) ? 
            <Layout>
              <Component {...props} />
            </Layout> :
            <AuthLayout>
              <Page404 />
            </AuthLayout> :
            <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/auth/sign-in' }} />
          )}
        />
      ))
    ) : (
      // Route item without children
      <Route
        key={index}
        path={path}
        exact
        render={props => (
          (checkIsAuth()) ? 
          (checkHasAccess(access)) ? 
            <Layout>
              <Component {...props} />
            </Layout> : 
            <AuthLayout>
              <Page404 />
            </AuthLayout> :
            (path !== "/auth/sign-in") ? 
            <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/auth/sign-in' }} /> : 
            <Layout>
              <Component {...props}  />
            </Layout>
        )}
      />
    )   );
```

and my render :

```
render() {
       return (   <Router>
     <ScrollToTop>
       <Switch>
         {childRoutes(DashboardLayout, dashboardRoutes)}
         {childRoutes(DashboardLayout, defaultRoutes)}
         {childRoutes(AuthLayout, signInRoutes)}
         <Route
           render={() => (
             (checkIsAuth()) ? 
             <AuthLayout>
               <Page404 />
             </AuthLayout> : 
             <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/auth/sign-in' }} />
           )}
         />
       </Switch>
     </ScrollToTop>   </Router> );   }
```

Someone already had this problem ?
Thanks in advance for help :)

Comment: Someone already had the same problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. The problem was from the template which used the same path to know the url params and to dislay url in href. I just create a new parameter in my component :

```
{
      path: "/callcenter/soundplayer",
      realPath: "/callcenter/soundplayer/:agentName?/:date?",
      name: "Audios",
      component: SoundFileRow,
      isShow: true,
      access: "staffAccess"
    },
```

Then I add it in my router.js :

```
    const childRoutes = (Layout, routes, navBarAccess) =>
routes.map(({ children, path, realPath, component: Component, access }, index) =>
  children ? (
      // Route item with children
      children.map(({ path, realPath, component: Component , access}, index) => (
        <Route
        key={index}
        path={realPath}
        exact
        render={props => (
          (checkIsAuth())? 
          checkHasAccess(access) ? 
          <Layout>
          <Component {...props} />
          </Layout> :
          <AuthLayout>
          <Page404 />
          </AuthLayout> :
          <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/auth/sign-in' }} />
          )}
        />
        ))
      ) : (
      // Route item without children
      <Route
      key={index}
      path={realPath}
      exact
      render={props => (
        (checkIsAuth()) ? 
        (checkHasAccess(access)) ? 
        <Layout>
        <Component {...props} />
        </Layout> : 
        <AuthLayout>
        <Page404 />
        </AuthLayout> :
        (path !== "/auth/sign-in") ? 
        <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/auth/sign-in' }} /> : 
        <Layout>
        <Component {...props}  />
        </Layout>
        )}
        />
        )
      );
```

Hope it will be usefull for someone on day !